# Custom viewpager page transition

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-transitions

I know that there are already a lot of questions about Timely UI. I am currently doing with **ViewPager** in which I have three pages with different background (green, yellow, red). I would like to implement **transition** between them as is shown in the picture below. I know how to implement a custom transition for ViewPager but I do not know what is the logic for this particular transition.

Does anyone have experience with this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That effect looks very nice. This blog post introduces a library to do it with a bitmap. 
http://andraskindler.com/blog/2014/parallaxviewpager_parallax_background_effect_for_the_viewpager/

I imagine this could be done just using this library and a correctly created picture file. I wonder that as it looks to be gradients on each page and gradients between each page (a gradient of gradients) if this could be done with a drawable. It might be easier to make it work well for different screen sizes.

I would start by working with the code provided in the library. 
https://github.com/andraskindler/parallaxviewpager/blob/master/src/main/java/com/andraskindler/parallaxviewpager/ParallaxViewPager.java